# Input Transformer: handle special characters in AWS Event Bridge

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, escaping, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I am having a hard time understanding why my input transformation is not working in Event Bridge.

The following is the default input to a step function, which will intentionally cause my state machine to fail:

```json
{
    "Comment": "Insert your JSON here"
}
```

I have configured a rule in EventBridge to notify the failure using the following Input Transformer:

```json
{
    "executionArn": "$.detail.executionArn",
    "inputs": "$.detail.input",
    "startDate": "$.detail.startDate",
    "status": "$.detail.status"
}
```

It uses the above input in this template:

```json
"Flow Execution Failure! More information: <executionArn> Status: <status> Started On: <startDate> Flow Input: <inputs>"
```

**The problem is** no matter however I try to include `<inputs>`, it fails. I believe it is because the event will contain the following newline characters `\n`:

```json
{
    ...
    "detail": {
        "status": "FAILED",
        "input": "{\n    \"Comment\": \"Insert your JSON here\"\n}"
    }
}
```

**I have tried** escaping `<input>` in the following manners, none of which worked so far:

- `Flow Input: \"<inputs>\"`
- `` Flow Input: `<inputs>` ``
- `` Flow Input: \"\`<inputs>\`\" ``

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.detail.input` is already an escaped json string, I’m not sure it’s going to be possible to nest that value within in another string.

Unless the `InputTemplate` *must* be a single string, it may be easier to change the template to something like:

```json
{
    "executionArn": <executionArn>,
    "inputs": <inputs>,
    "startDate": <startDate>,
    "status": <status>
}
```